# how to change ringer mode in background(Vibrate or Silent)

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-calendar, android-audiomanager, android-vibration

I'm trying to write a program in which user can set time that will change ringer mode to vibrate or normal in background. When I set the start time it's working but at the end time it's not changing and device continuing vibrate mode.
I just want, at the start time phone would be in vibrate and at end time phone would go back into the silent mode.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private AlarmManager alarmManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();


    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 37);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, (int)System.currentTimeMillis(), myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 38);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);

    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver1.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, (int)System.currentTimeMillis(), myIntent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}}
```

and these are related BroadcastReceiver class..

**MyReceiver.java**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)arg0.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    switch(audio.getRingerMode()){
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL :
        audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        Log.d("MODE", "was normal");
        Log.d("MODE", "is vibrate");
        break;

    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT :
        audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        Log.d("MODE", "was silent");
        Log.d("MODE", "is vibrate");
        break;
    }
}}
```

**MyReceiver1.java**

```
public class MyReceiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AudioManager audio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(audio.getRingerMode()){
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL :
        audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        Log.d("MODE", "was normal");
        Log.d("MODE", "is silent");
        break;
    }

    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE :
        audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        Log.d("MODE", "was vibrate");
        Log.d("MODE", "is silent");
        break;
    }
}}
```

and I declared

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED" /> 
        </intent-filter>  
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver1">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED" /> 
        </intent-filter>  
    </receiver>
```

in my manifest file.

Please help me to solve this issue. 
Thanks.

Comment: Is there any solution??

Answer (score 0):

Dont't use both the receiver (MyReceiver and Myreceiver1) use single MyReceiver.

```js
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED" /> 
        </intent-filter>  
    </receiver>
```