# Alarm manager is not working as expected

Tags: android, android-alarms

Basically, I want to create two alarms:

1. Fire daily at 6 PM
2. Fire monthly at a specific date at 4 PM.

But issues are after executing monthly alarm first one is also executing at 4 PM.

Following way I am creating alarm:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();

// For 1st alarm
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

// For 2nd alarm
calendar1.set(2017,8,17,16,00,00);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
bundle.putInt("NotificationId1", 1);
bundle.putInt("NotificationId2", 2);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1,
                               intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2,
                               intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(),  pendingIntent1);
```

And after firing monthly alarm I am again defining alarm with the further date.

Issue is after firing monthly alarm first alarm is executing at 4 pm. How to resolve the issue?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: create 2 objects of `Alarm` class

Answer (score 0):

your first alarm is repeating so create alarm like these to set alarm.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
        setExact(...);
    }
    else{
        set(...);
    }
}
else{
    setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(...);
}
```

now in your broadcast receiver set next alarm to fire for next day at 4pm

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 intent.
Because you are sharing the same intent, any alarm running will also call the same intent.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I hope you will get your answer.

```
Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
bundle1.putInt("NotificationId1", 1);
intent1.putExtras(bundle1);

Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
bundle2.putInt("NotificationId2", 2);
intent2.putExtras(bundle2);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1,
                               intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2,
                               intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your both the alarms separate from each other. For this you need 2 intents, 2 pending intent and 2 alarm managers. You can take a reference from  - [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893727/how-to-change-ringer-mode-in-backgroundvibrate-or-silent)

your code should be like-

```
// define variables
private AlarmManager alarmMgr1;
private AlarmManager alarmMgr2;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent1;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent2;
private Calendar timeFirst;
private Calendar timeSecond;
private Context context;

// init variables
timeFirst = Calendar.getInstance();
timeSecond = Calendar.getInstance();
timeFirst.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
timeFirst.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
timeFirst.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
timeFirst.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

timeSecond.set(2017,8,17,16,00,00);

// set values
alarmMgr1 = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmMgr2 = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), myIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), myIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

alarmMgr1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeFirst.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent1);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
    alarmMgr2.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeSecond.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);
}
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
        alarmMgr2.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeSecond.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);
}
else{
    alarmMgr2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeSecond.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);
}

}
```

hope it will be helpful and give you a better idea.